# Create a circular or triangular shaped board

Tags: css, reactjs, shapes

I'm trying to create a game board ( similar to a chess board) for a game in react, and I would like to arrenge the cells (rectangular divs, that take they're value from a state array) in different shapes ( circle, triangle, oval etc) thus creating a board of that shape.
I only know how to arrange divs with CSS flex or grid and that is always rectangular formation (as far as I know)

How can I achieve this?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What if you make each cell `position:absolute` and put them all inside a containing div with `position:relative`? Could you set their position in code so they're in a circle? [Something like this](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/) but dynamic

Comment: @JakobLovern  technically yes, but it's hard work if I need to arrenge 100 elements or more and I need to position each element individually. I hope there is an easier solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To dynamically position elements, you need to arrange them in code. We can do that by *creating* the elements in code, then setting their position programmatically. I'm working off [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6toer8ab/2/)

First, the HTML:

```html
<div id="my_container" />
```

It couldn't get simpler. We just want somewhere we can put our elements. Now, for minimal styling, we've got:

```css
#my_container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: powderblue
}

.cell {
  background-color: red;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

I've added colors so that you can see the elements in the generated output, but they're not necessary. What *is* necessary is those `position` lines. Making the `#container` div relative lets it behave nicely with whatever it's placed in, and making each of the `.cell` divs `absolute` causes them to be placed on absolute coordinates relative to their parent, which means we can put them where we want. Ok, what's next?

The cells. I assume your cells already exist, but since I don't have them, I've created code to build these cells, shown below:

```js
const container = document.getElementById("my_container");
const number_of_cells = 30;
const cells = [];
for (var i = 0; i < number_of_cells; i++)
{
    const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.classList.add("cell");
    container.appendChild(newDiv)
    cells.push(newDiv); 
}
```

The goal here is to put the cells as children of `#my_container` and also create an array of all the cells. (I think maybe this step is redundant but I don't care...It makes the next step easier.)

```js
function PositionCells(cells, x, y, radius)
{
  const incr_angle = (2*Math.PI)/cells.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
      var new_x = x+radius * Math.cos(incr_angle * i);
      var new_y = y+radius * Math.sin(incr_angle * i);
      cells[i].style.left = new_x+'px';
      cells[i].style.top = new_y+'px';
  }
}
PositionCells(cells, 50,50,30);
```

Basically what I've done is written a function to position all the cells in an ordered, programmatic way. If you want other shapes, you can pretty easily do the math to come up with where to position them.

And that's it!

Comment: Is there a way to fill the inside of the circle also with cells? To create a "board"? Because I will need to check each of the cells neighbors eventually

Comment: Probably! If I were to fill the circle, I'd partition the set of cells into smaller groups (maybe 8?) and run the above code on each group with increasing radiuses to get that "circular grid" look. For a triangular grid, I think I'd use parallelogram grids and just handle the diagonal.

Comment: [This forked fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g24arkpb/) of the above code shows the positioning technique for filled circles.